# ListView doesn't update its content after item deleted

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on Xamarin.Forms in C#. My **ListView** is able to show data from the database. I have also added `MenuItem` with click event handler at the code behind. When I hold to delete (**Android**) the item, `MenuItem_Clicked` is invoked and `_students` is updated (my selected item was removed) but my **ListView** still does not update.

My View:

```
<ListView x:Name="listStudents" Refreshing="listStudents_Refreshing" 
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Text="Delete" Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <StackLayout Padding="20">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;

public ListView_SearchBar()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var _students = SQLite_DB.SeedStudentData();
    _students = new ObservableCollection<Student>(_students);
    listStudents.ItemsSource = _students;
}

private void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listStudents.IsRefreshing = true;
    _students.Remove((sender as MenuItem).CommandParameter as Student);
    listStudents.ItemsSource = null;
    listStudents.ItemsSource = _students;
    listStudents.IsRefreshing = false;
    return;
}
```

Comment: in this line `_students.Remove..` 

 **`_students`** will be null 

and throw an exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Actually I didn't get that error

Comment: then you must be doing something different than what the posted code does.  The posted code declares `_students` as a local variable in the constructor.  Also, if you are using an ObservableCollection you should not need to reassign the ItemsSource.

Comment: Why do you define variables with the same name, one global and one local?  one is :`private ObservableCollection<Student> _students; `, another is `var _students = SQLite_DB.SeedStudentData();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i modify your code behind as follows, the **ListView** updates correctly on my side:

```
private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;

public ListView_SearchBar()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _students = SQLite_DB.SeedStudentData();
    _students = new ObservableCollection<Student>(_students);
    listStudents.ItemsSource = _students;
}

private void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listStudents.IsRefreshing = true;
    _students.Remove((sender as MenuItem).CommandParameter as Student);
    listStudents.ItemsSource = null;
    listStudents.ItemsSource = _students;
    listStudents.IsRefreshing = false;
    return;
}
```

Note that i removed the `var` signature of your first use of `_student` in your page constructor.

Comment: I made the changes accordingly but still the listview doesn't refresh.

Comment: @Steve, then you will have to provide more details about your exact configuration

Comment: I have uploaded the issue as video here - https://youtu.be/N33lB7rSs3A. Not so sure how to embed the video to stackoverflow. The code-behind does updated the list count from 3 to 2, but in my program app, it doesn't.

Comment: @Steve, I would suggest that you reduce your code to a minimal where the issue still occurs: a xaml and a code behind file, and you share with us that exact sample so that we have something to grasp. Also let us know what is your system configuration: XF version, etc